# MVC how to pass the updated Model back to a controller through an Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, html.actionlink

So I have the following view in MVC4:

```
@model ViewModel

@section Sidebar
{
    <ul style="margin-left:-20px">
        ...
        <li>
           @Html.ActionLink(@menuItem.Name, @menuItem.ActionName, @menuItem.ControllerName, @Model, new { id = @menuItem.Name + "MenuItemId", style = "font-weight: bold;", @class = "loading" })
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <article class="widget widgetFullPage" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h2 id="Details">GENERAL INFORMATION</h2>
        <table>
            <tr id="Row1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td id="VarOneId" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px; width: 300px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.VarOne, null, new { style = "width:100px;" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <tr id="RowX">
                <td>
                    <input value=" " class="nextbutton loading" type="submit" id="NextButton" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>
}
```

The Submit button in the form works just fine, but I also want to pass the updated model (whatever the user has already typed) through the Html.ActionLink to a different controller in the Sidebar section above, when the user clicks on the sidebar link instead of the submit button.

What I have seems to only pass back the Model with data that's initially passed into the View, not the updated values from the page.  What would I need to do to get the updated model and pass that back through the ActionLink?

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the client. In any case you should not be sending a model to a GET method (it creates an ugly query string, will throw an exception if the resulting query string exceeds the character limit and binding will fail if the model contains properties which are collections or complex objects. One option is to have 2 submit buttons in the form (with name/value attributes) and in the controller check which button was clicked and redirect as required.

Comment: FYI You are also opening yourself up to a `http verb tempering hack` , so you should define `[HttpGet]` on your controller. I might be wrong but you should be creating model definitions in the controller not trying to pass them in the url. That might be an objective idea , and i understand it is not answering your question. Just ... views should be squeaky clean

Comment: To acheive that,you have to serialize your form into a url parameter format or some json and then to read it from your controller. Yet that's not a very good practice.